# Rails how to deal with web assets in test mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, testing, assets

We've got a few JavaScripts in our rails app that are loaded from the web, such as Olark, but they tend to cause our tests to become slow and unreliable. We've started just conditionally loading them depending on whether we're in test mode, but I was wondering if there's a better approach. We'd also like to use web fonts, but are considering downloading them just for this case. It seems a little strange to compromise web performance for test performance, though. What is a good way of handling situations like this?